# Como pegar letras especificas de uma string - Swift2

Tags: string, swift

Como eu faço para pegar uma `letra` especifica de uma variável?

```
var variavel = "teste";
```

Eu gostaria de pegar uma `letra separada`, preciso colocar cada letra em uma variável diferente

Obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi porque negativaram.. +1

Answer (score 4):

Você pode acessar a propriedade `characters` de uma `String` e usar ela pra extrair um `array` de seus caracteres. Se você quiser um `array` de `String` pra cada `Character` você precisa usar o método `map` para transformar o `[Character]` em `[String]`.

```
let str = "teste"
let strCharactersArray = Array(str.characters) // ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]
let strStringArray = str.characters.map{String($0)} // ["t", "e", "s", "t", "e"]
```

Para voce percorrer cada letra da String voce pode usar o loop `for` `in`:

```
for character in str.characters {
    print(character)
}
```

Comment: Perfeito!

Muito obrigado!

Comment: @BrunoBafilli se a resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como certa clicando no sinal `✓` á esquerda da resposta.